# Teradata SQL enable_quoted_identifiers

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying set 'enable_quoted_identifiers ='off' ' as i am able to do this in SQL Server for the intention of changing the where clause to allow both single quotes AND double quotes for string literals.  However, I am having trouble figuring out how to do this in Teradata(it is pretty straight forward in SQL Server).

The code i found on Teradata documents states:

```
'Set Session enable_quoted_identifiers = {'off'};
followed by code....
```

in an ideal world the code i am trying to run looks like this:

```
Set session enable_quoted_identifiers = {'off'};
select ID, Name
from DB.Table
where Name in ('name1',"name2")
;
```

I know this can be done manually, however i am trying to inject a sql output list into a query in teradata via python.  Again, i can do this in SQL Server, but i need to be able to have the flexibility of having single/double quotes around string literals.  Am I missing something or is my syntax incorrect?

Thank you

Comment: The syntax you found is probably from Teradata Aster, there's no way to treat double quoted names as string literals. But why do you *need to be able to have the flexibility of having single/double quotes around string literals*, if you try *to inject a sql output list into a query in teradata via python*?

Comment: simply pre-process the values in python, replacing wrapping doubles with singles.